# How to flatten and subtract columns with pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm just learning pig; how can I take this:

((a,b),c,(x,y),z)

And get something like this:

(a,b,c,x,y,z, ABS(c-z))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much exactly how you wrote it.

```
A = load 'foobar' as (t:((a:double,b:double),c:double,(x:double,y:double,)z:double));
B = foreach A generate flatten(t);
C = foreach B generate a, b, c, x, y, z, ABS(c-z);
```

I assumed double as datatype for the values. Not 100% sure on the flatten, depending on your exact schema this might produce unwanted values, in the case described here it should simply remove the internal brackets.

Comment: Ah - I was trying something very close to this, but had no luck.  I think I'm somewhat confused on how to reference the column/variable names.  Also, when you did:  B = foreach A generate flatten(t);  why did you not have to do flatten(x)?

Comment: Well, you weren't super clear on the structure of the data. I assumed that you have one big tuple, with the two embedded tuples, so simply flattening the big outer tuple should do the trick.

Comment: When I get back to my computer, I will give it all a try.  I do appreciate your help.